How do I construct "pathological" sequences?
In analysis, one often wants to prove statements to the effect of:

if $X$ is locally compact and equipped with a Radon measure $\mu$, then $C^0_c(X)$ will not be complete with respect to the $L^p(X, \mu)$-norm for any finite $p \geq 1$.

I personally would attempt to prove that:

if $X$ is locally compact and equipped with a Radon measure $\mu$, then $C^0_c(X)$ will be dense inside $L^p(X, \mu)$ for finite $p \geq 1$"

and then deduce the first result from this lemma. However, it seems to me that analysts would try to come up with a sequence of compactly supported functions on $X$ that converge to some discontinuous $L^p$-function on $X$, and I'm wondering if anyone has tips on how to come up with such sequences ? Thanks!
